# Find eqns of the lines contained in plane $y-2z=0$ and passing thorugh point $(0,2,1)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors

In order for the generic line $l$ passing through point $A$ to be contained in  plane $\alpha$ there're 2 conditions:

1) $A \in \alpha$ must hold (for this case it's true);

2) directional vector $\mathbf{v}$ of the line and normal vector $\mathbf{n}$ to the plane must be perpendicular, i.e. $\mathbf{v}\cdot \mathbf{n}=0$.

We know that $\mathbf{n}_\pi=(0,1,-2)$ while we don't know $\mathbf{v}_r=(p,q,r)$. Then,
\begin{equation}
(0,1,-2)\cdot(p,q,r)=q-2r=0\Rightarrow q=2r\end{equation}

If we consider the star having $A$ as its midpoint, we have
\begin{equation}
 \dfrac{x-x_A}{p}=\dfrac{y-y_A}{q}=\dfrac{z-z_A}{r}\Rightarrow\dfrac{x}{p}=\dfrac{y-2}{2r}=\dfrac{z-1}{r}
\end{equation}
valid under the condition that $p,r\neq 0$. So infinitely many lines satisfying the assignment.

Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

Point $(0,2,1)$ locates in plane $y−2z=0$ which is parallel to x axis.So the general form of equation of line on this plane passing the point $(0, 2, 1)$is in following form:

$\frac{y−2}{q}=\frac{z−1}{r}$

The condition is:

$ q . 1+r.(−2)=0$.

This equation can have infinitely many solutions that is there are infinitely many lines with required condition.So your result is correct except your formula for the equation of the line.